# Python - Beautifulsoup - parse multiple span elements

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to extract title from 'span'.

Using the below code as an example, the output I am looking for is 6536 and 9319, which are part of 'title'. Seen below:

span aria-label="6536 users starred this repository" class="Counter js-social-count" data-plural-suffix="users starred this repository" data-singular-suffix="user starred this repository" data-turbo-replace="true" data-view-component="true" id="repo-stars-counter-star" title="**6,536**">6.5k</span

I'm having trouble parsing in the last line of code get_text(). I think we could potentially use regex to parse socialstars but I'm not sure how.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

websites = ['https://github.com/marketplace/actions/yq-portable-yaml-processor','https://github.com/marketplace/actions/TruffleHog-OSS']

for links in websites:
URL = requests.get(links)
detailsoup = BeautifulSoup(URL.content, "html.parser")

# Extract stars
socialstars = detailsoup.findAll('span', {'class': 'Counter js-social-count'})
socialstarsList = [socialstars.get_text() for socialstars in socialstars]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the urls into a list and iterated over the list of urls and as the  each  webpage stars contain the same `id`. So you have to select only a single that's enough.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

websites = ['https://github.com/marketplace/actions/yq-portable-yaml-processor','https://github.com/marketplace/actions/TruffleHog-OSS']

for links in websites:
    URL = requests.get(links)
    detailsoup = BeautifulSoup(URL.content, "html.parser")

    # Extract stars
    socialstars = detailsoup.select_one('#repo-stars-counter-star').get('title')
    print(socialstars)
```

**Output:**

```
 6,536
 9,319
```